# Running JUnit with Arquillian on tomcat remote 7 tries to load ...remote_6.TomcatRemoteExtension

Tags: tomcat7, jboss-arquillian

I want to run my test with Arquillian on tomcat remote 7. Here's a very simple example to reproduce my issue.

**pom dependencies**:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-tomcat-remote-7</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.CR5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**arqullian.xml**:

http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

```
<container qualifier="tomcat-remote-7">
    <configuration>
        <property name="host">localhost</property>
        <property name="jmxPort">8089</property>
        <property name="bindHttpPort">8080</property>
        <property name="user">arquillian</property>
        <property name="pass">arquillian</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

**SimpleTest.java**

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class SimpleTest {
@Deployment
@OverProtocol("Servlet 3.0")
public static Archive<WebArchive> createDeployment()    {
    File warFile = new File("../myproject/target/mywar.war");
    WebArchive webArchive = ShrinkWrap.createFromZipFile(WebArchive.class, warFile);
    return webArchive;
}

@Test
public void testSimple() {
    assertTrue(true);
}
```

}

After running the SimpleTest I get long stacktrace, where in the end I see:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.jboss.arquillian.container.tomcat.remote_6.TomcatRemoteExtension
```

**I wonder why it tries to load TomcatRemoteExtension for version 6 when I have in the dependency version 7**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the extension is not properly registered.

Look for the file META-INF/services/org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.LoadableExtension inside arquillian-tomcat-remote-7.jar and edit it.

You should see the incorrect reference to remote_6. Change it to remote_7 and everything should work as expected.

It seems to be already fixed in master: https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-tomcat/commit/3084c7f1be4320cc4e795385e4513f25f6d5a0e0